# SAS: Conditional Count and Range?

Tags: date, count, conditional-statements, sas, range

I have a dataset with three columns: ID, Date of Action A, Date of Action B.

ID |  DateofActionA  |      DateofActionB

123 | July 1, 2020  |   July 15, 2020

123 | July 1, 2021  |   August 19, 2021

123 | July 1, 2022  |   November 3, 2022

123 | July 1, 2023  |   July 14, 2023

123  | July 1, 2023 |   November 14, 2023

123 | July 1, 2024  |   November 15, 2024

456 | March 3, 2020 | March 4, 2020

456 | March 3, 2023 |   April 5, 2023

456 | March 3, 2024 |   May  3, 2024

I like the output to be 3 columns: ID, Date of Action A, and Want.
The column Want is: count of Date of Action B under the condition that it's within 2 years of Date of Action A.

I want the following output:

ID  | DateofActionA |   Want

123 | July 1, 2020  |   0

123 | July 1, 2021  |   1

123 | July 1, 2022  |   2

123 | July 1, 2023  |   2

123 | July 1, 2024  |   3

456 | March 3, 2020 |   0

456 |   March 3, 2023   |   0

456 |   March 3, 2024   |   1

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to explain what you want in more detail? The Date of Action B is a date, so I'm not sure how you'd "count" that (it seems to be cumulative within ID over time?), and in your example *everything* seems to be within 2 years of Date of Action A but not everything gets counted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID (DateofActionA DateofActionB)(:yymmdd10.);
format DateofActionA DateofActionB yymmdd10.;
datalines;
123 2020-07-01 2020-07-15 
123 2021-07-01 2021-08-19 
123 2022-07-01 2022-11-03 
123 2023-07-01 2023-07-14 
123 2023-07-01 2023-11-14 
123 2024-07-01 2024-11-15 
456 2020-03-03 2020-03-04 
456 2023-03-03 2023-04-05 
456 2024-03-03 2024-05-03 
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select ID
        , DateofActionA
        , (select count(*) 
           from have as b
           where a.ID = b.ID
             and b.DateofActionB between intnx('year', a.DateofActionA, -2, 's') 
                                 and a.DateofActionA) as count
   from have as a
   ;
quit;
```

**Result:**

```
ID   DateofActionA  count
123  2020-07-01     0
123  2021-07-01     1
123  2022-07-01     2
123  2023-07-01     2
123  2023-07-01     2
123  2024-07-01     3
456  2020-03-03     0
456  2023-03-03     0
456  2024-03-03     1
```